# Unable to launch ethconsole with eth (cpp-ethereum) (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ubuntu, ipc, console

I successfully launched a node. Everything works fine, even GPU mining. Except I'm unable to connect with ethconsole, as I get an error message :

```
$ethconsole
Connecting to node at /home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc
Uncaught exception: Error: Cannot find module 'process'
```

And then I have to hit CTRL+C to stop it as it seems to be stuck (tried to wait up to 15 min..).

I already tried

```
$sudo apt-get install process
```

and

```
$sudo npm install process
```

but that is not the way to solve the problem obviously!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try  sudo npm install process

Comment: didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo npm install -g process
```

You missed the g.